# If iPhone landscape is wCompact-hCompact, why does it look so wrong?

Tags: xcode, ios9, xcode7

I've created a single-view calculator app and I'm practising with different layouts for different device orientations.

I'm modifying **wAny-hCompact** and **wAny-hRegular**. I've got a stackview for my <kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>CE</kbd> and <kbd>⌫</kbd> buttons. I've set the stackview to be vertical normally, but for *regular height* to be horizontal. This looks great.

***The Stackview:***

[image: stackview-attributes]

***wAny-hCompact:***

[image: wAny-hCompact]

***wAny-hRegular:***

[image: wAny-hRegular]

## Problem

The problem is that when I run my application in the emulator it looks wrong. I've tried iPhone 5s, iPhone 6 and iPhone 6s. They all have the same problem.

According to [my source](http://sizeclasses.com/) these devices are

- wCompact-hRegular in portrait
- wCompact-hCompact in landscape

So why does it look like this? Why does it look correct in Xcode but not in an emulator?

Why do the iPhone emulators think that they are **regular height** in landscape?

*Note: There are no errors or warnings in my app. I have only the minimum constraints to make it work and the constraints are completely separated to the two different base orientation types (wAny-hCompact and wAny-hRegular).*

### iPhone 6 Portrait (correct)

[image: iphone-portrait]

### iPhone 6 Landscape (wrong)

[image: iphone-landscape]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem. Here's how:

1. Grab the <kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>CE</kbd> and <kbd>⌫</kbd> stack view and move it somewhere else within the view (anywhere)
2. Updates Frames

Although everything looked identical, when I re-ran the application, everything looked correct even when in landscape. I guess it was bugged or glitched somehow.